# Why can't I access this variable which is defined inside a method?

Tags: python, variables, methods, undefined, global

I have put a variable that gets updated inside a small method but when I go to use it later on in my code in different methods it shows up as undefined. Do I somehow have to make this variable global? If yes, how would I do that? Here's the code:

```
def getval():
    threading.Timer(0.5, getval).start()
    time_interval = slide.get()
    print(time_interval)


getval()
```

This method essentially takes the value (integer) from the scale widget (a slider) in python and updates it every half a second. I then later use the `time_interval` variable to control different timings.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mihkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Mihkel/Documents/PyCharm/main.py", line 40, in optionselected
    rb()
  File "C:/Users/Mihkel/Documents/PyCharm/main.py", line 86, in rb
    re()
  File "C:/Users/Mihkel/Documents/PyCharm/main.py", line 75, in re
    root.after(time_interval, blu)
NameError: name 'time_interval' is not defined
```

Comment: `time_interval` is local to `getval`. I suggest learning about the scoping rules.

Comment: Add `global time_interval` in the first line of `getval`'s definition.